# Why do I have to go through a moderator to migrate my own question?

Tags: discussion, migration

As a relatively new Stack Exchange user, I ended up with a question that should've been asked on a different SE site. Someone suggested in a comment that it be migrated to another site, which I attempted to do.

**Problem 1:** I couldn't intuitively find out how to migrate a question. I had to Google "how to migrate question stack exchange" to discover it was under the "close" menu (which as a noob I honestly didn't realize was a menu). Since I didn't actually want to close the question, just migrate it, this was non-obvious. This is out of the scope of this question, but thought I'd document it anyway.

**Problem 2:** Once I figured out how to migrate a question, the site I wanted to migrate it to was not listed [1]! Once again, I had to search on Meta Stack Exchange to figure out how to get my question onto one of the unlisted sites. I don't understand why I have to go through a moderator to migrate *my own question*.

So, to restate my question, why can't I migrate my question to any other SE site without having to flag it for review by a moderator?

[1] Yes, I realize this has been discussed in other questions.

**Edit:** As discussed in the comments below, it's often low-quality questions that people would attempt to migrate. Perhaps if there were a reputation threshold at which people could be trusted to migrate their own questions?

Comment: Because it takes an experienced eye to see if and when migration is appropriate. You as the user can always delete in one place and re-post in the other, in any case.

Comment: Quality questions fit for migration are the exception, not the norm, I am afraid.

Comment: `Quality questions fit for migration are the exception` Ah, that's a pity.

Comment: Most people that post in the wrong place did so because they didn't bother to read the help material presented. Such people *tend* to not put much effort into their question either.

Comment: Maybe it could be a rep-based thing? I've got over 1k rep (I know that's not a *lot*) so maybe I could be trusted to migrate my own stuff if I realize I posted on the wrong site.

Comment: @ThaneBrimhall It's not about rep on the site the question is coming from, it's about rep on the site the question is going to.  I can know when a question is offtopic on Stack Overflow, but I won't know whether that question is on topic on whatever site migration is being proposed for.

Comment: Basically we're really good at the "not here" type of migration @ThaneBrimhall. We might perfectly recognize that something is not a good fit for "our" site, but that doesn't mean we understand the target site.

Comment: There is a constant, irrational resistance in the moderators - siteadmins against the question migrations. The background is maybe some like of power statusquo between the different site moderators, although it is only an assumption. If you want a correct and an efficient migration system, they will destroy your account. Real explanation is what you never get from them. Migration between the SO sites is in most cases practically impossible, and if you are digging around this thema, they will handle this as an agressive action.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: "they will destroy your account" [citation needed]. I don't know what your problem with migrations is, but you're blowing it completely out of proportion.

Comment: @Mat Ok. Here is a list of deleted question from SO: http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions-top100.html

Comment: @PeterHorvath: what does that have to do with migrations?

Comment: @Mat Groundless deletions (even very good questions), and the irrational, pointless resistence against the migrations are the heads of the same hydra. As you can see, some of the listed questions were finally undeleted/migrated to programmers SE.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: if by that you mean that keeping questions on-topic and not moving crap around are part of SE's core, then you're spot on indeed.

Comment: @Mat No. There is a big list of well-reputed popular question, which were simply deleted without any explanation. There is a resistance against any correct migration system without any explanation (see Servy's surreal "explanation" below if you wish).

Comment: @PeterHorvath: popular != on-topic. Deleted not without reason, but because they attract similar questions, see off-topic again. Migrations are treated with care for the same reason: each site has its own scope and topic, and a lot of people don't understand that. If the model of having many sites with narrow topics and strict policies doesn't suit you, you're on the wrong network I'm afraid.

Comment: @Mat Most of these questions were popular & ontopic.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: "Were" is not "now". Standards have changed. Feel free to open a new question to discuss your belief that this change is for the worse, but don't just ignore the fact that *it has happened*. (And for the record, you haven't provided a list of these "popular *and* on-topic questions". Linking to the top 100 deletions on a mirror doesn't help your case in the slightest.)

Comment: @JonathanGarber I tried that already. If I open new questions, I will get brutal downvotes, just as the most good initiatives here (see for example this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231986/are-some-of-stack-overflows-rules-anti-intellectual-at-their-core ). After some (5 or so - the clear number is secret) such questions, the OP is automatically banned from the site practically forever. So I am practically not allowed to open new questions. And I provided a big list of very problematic deletions 40 min ago: http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions-top100.html

Comment: @PeterHorvath: Downvotes on Meta.SO no longer affect reputation, so asking such a question there should be relatively consequence-free. As to the link, I saw it, and even referenced it. Those are not "problematical deletions". "[Favorite programmer cartoon](http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions/845/56.html)". "[Clearing the mind after a day of coding](http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions/784/461.html)". "[Worst pop culture perversion of programming](http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions/175/074.html)". I honestly don't see how you can claim such stuff should remain on the site.

Comment: @JonathanGarber First: It isn't MSO, but MSE, which is an independent site with an independent reputation. Second: after some (around 5) hardly downvoted questions, the site automatically bans you from here practically forever, which rule still applies on the metas just as here on MSE as well. I want to gratulate you and to the upvoter of your comment for the perfect knowledge of the system.

Comment: @PeterHorvath I'm not seeing an explanation of why "Favorite programmer cartoon" is on topic in your reply.  Perhaps you forgot to include it.

Comment: @Servy I admit, that (on my opinion) this question is clearly offtopic on SO and probably offtopic on programmers SE. But I won't make a debate about a single question. I want you to check these questions, and make a general image if they were deleted based on a fair deletion policy, or not.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: No, you missed the point. You're complaining about deletions of SO questions. If you genuinely think that that's a problem, ASK ON MSO. If you're talking about the broader network, cite some examples off of SO. As to the question ban on non-reputation meta sites, that's an artifact that should be looked at, if it is indeed the case. (I'm not going to go into whether question-banning on Meta.SE is a good or bad thing. That's a religious argument I'm not willing to get into.)

Comment: @JonathanGarber I think you have partially right, and this is really depends on the MSO/MSE split. Imho it was a wonderful invention, and helped a lot on the system. It seems, SE (as the company) wants to somehow prevent what to wikipedia happened. Maybe I should wait a little bit with my critics, maybe the system repaired itself at least partially. Thank you!

Comment: @PeterHorvath: Do note that I'm not saying that the question ban doesn't exist on per-site metas, (I genuinely don't know,) just that because there's no reputation loss associated with downvotes there, it doesn't make as much sense. I'll have a look at that later.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: As a moderator, I can tell you for sure that there are no power struggles between moderators over migration. If the question is off-topic on one site, on-topic on another, and is not crap, it will be migrated. It's simple. As for why you need moderators, because when you get 5 people who can vote to close, and each wants to migrate to one site, you can't keep up. So you need someone with a binding vote to decide (read: moderator). Also, that's how the system is made. Also, just because you want to migrate your question to a different site, doesn't mean it's going to be accepted.

Comment: @JonathanGarber It doesn't exist. Of course there are always suspensions if things get out of hand, but there's no ban to worry about.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quite simply, because so few people can get it right.  Lots of people are able to recognize when a question is not appropriate for the site they are on.  Very few people are capable of determining what site a given offtopic question *does* belong on.

Someone generally needs to be an active member of the site that the question should be migrated to in order to know whether or not the question is actually on topic on that site, and that it actually meets the standard for migration.

To make matters worse, while most people *don't* know whether or not a question belongs on a given site, they often *think* that they do.  They don't realize that they don't know the standards and scope of other sites.

Of migrations posted to moderators, they have regularly commented that there is a very low hit rate of questions that should actually be migrated.  If we allowed users to migrate questions without moderator involvement, they'd just continue shipping over questions that don't belong, forcing other sites to deal with the inappropriate questions that is being exported.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. In that case, perhaps I'll open up a new feature suggestion about migrating questions.

Comment: "Very few people are capable of determining what site a given offtopic question does belong on." You are increasing surreal. Practically every single commenter is capable to decide to understand what is the difference between "math" and "android".

Comment: @PeterHorvath That's just it though.  Not all math questions belong on math.SE.  Not all questions about android belong on android.SE.  Not all programming questions belong on Stack Overflow.  Not all server configuration questions belong on Server Fault.  People like you look at a question, go "oh, that's about androids, it belongs on android.SE", and then the android users see the question and go "wow, this question doesn't meet a bunch of our guidelines, close.  Wish those SO users would stop sending us bad questions."  This isn't theoretical, we have hard migration stats on this.

Comment: If the common impression and some sophisticated site standards differ, the question had to be migrated to the relevant SE site. It is the logical consequence, and exactly this is what seldom happens in place of the unexplained closing/deleting of the question.

Comment: @PeterHorvath When people post questions on the entirely wrong site in the first place, there's a pretty high probability that the question, as it stands, isn't fit for *any* SE site.  Migration is reserved for questions that are already great questions, not questions that the target site is going to just need to close and spend effort trying to fix up.  By and large, people that ask great questions take the time to figure out which site they belong on before asking them.

Comment: Why? If the receiving site didn't want a question, it could send it further, or even delete it. But it were also possible if somebody fixed the question. It were a cooperative effort for something good. It were the logical way.

Comment: @PeterHorvath It's the "not in my backyard" mentality.  It results in communities just exporting their trash elsewhere instead of dealing with it themselves.  It creates tons of work for everyone involved and has no real benefits.  This isn't a hypothetical issue.  It was a major problem with a number of migration paths in the past.  They were causing way more harm than good on the target sites, to the point that the migration paths needed to be removed entirely.

Comment: @Servy You are the first, who fairly admits this "not in my backyard" mentality. Thank you! Also I assumed same like this. Why do you think communities misused a more liberal migration system? SE has a very sophisticated system to handle a very broad range of possible mis-usages, and uses the least prohibition. Only this case is an exception, why? What were your problem if the receiving site could vote if they want the question or not?

Comment: @PeterHorvath It's adding needless additional work.  Instead of spending all of the effort to migrate a question that's just going to be rejected, it can simply be closed right from the start, not requiring another community to go through all of the effort of evaluating and then closing the question.  As I said, this is not a hypothetical.  This policy exists because this was an actual problem, in practice, throughout the site's history.  People have shown that they're simply bad at migrating things, and the failed attempts were causing more harm than good.